# Черный экран во время работы в приложение только на Samsung s8+

Tags: java, android, samsung

Во время работы с моим приложение на Samsung s8+ очень редко появляется черный экран и телефон попадает в блокировку.
Кто нибудь знает в чем может быть проблема.
Логов нет так как это происходит у клиентов.
Может ли это связано что в приложении JobService постоянно выполняет работу ?

Comment: Черный экран и блокировка ? Можно поподробнее ? Интересно стало )

Comment: @GinTasan да, черный экран на 1-2 секунды потом телефон уходит в экран блокировки после ввода код и открытии телефона от блокировки 1 секунду стоит черный экран и потом приложение открывает первый экран

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте Nekbakht,

Думаю вы используете старые библиотеки которые не доступны на androidx, с оболочкой для samsung s8, s8+ и еще на два смартфона не помню какие с этим есть проблемы, вы можете заменить все библиотеки или же просто не обращать внимание, это происходит со многими приложениями и очень редко, так же Samsung обещало выложить обновление с исправлением этой проблемы.